# Keyboard tags could use some love

Tags: discussion, design

Some of us have been asking for something nicer for the `<kbd>` tag.

Jin mentioned [maybe polishing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=640141#640141) them up to make questions [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/keyboard-shortcuts-in-unity) look nicer, just documenting that here.

(Also note, I love my IBM Model M more than anyone, no need to accuse me of keyism. :p)

Comment: what's wrong with the style? It seems fine to me

Comment: @JeffAtwood I agree with Jorge on this one. It's just a flat, boxy grey with monospace text, and it looks dated to me... like Windows 98 kind of dated. It makes key combinations more readable than just plain text, but it could still look a little better than what it is now.